# bat file to delete files using path from argument

Tags: batch-file

I have been trying to get this stupid BAT file to run and am having issues: I want to pass it a path to a directory and delete everything (folders/files) in it. However the bat file just deletes everything where it is currently located. I believe the issue is in the parameter not getting set but I don't understand where I am going wrong.

Command:

```
delete.bat "C:\deleteme\"
```

Tried setting parameter these ways:

```
SET deletePath = %~1
SET deletePath = "%~1"
SET deletePath = %1
SET deletePath = "%1"
```

Echoing the parameter never prints the value passed.

```
if "%~1"=="" goto BLANK 
if NOT "%~1"=="" goto DELETE 


:BLANK
ECHO Need delete path passed as parameter
TIMEOUT 10
END
Exit


:DELETE
SET deletePath = %~1
echo %deletePath%
pause
del %deletePath%. /F /Q 
rmdir /s .q %deletePath%
END
exit
```

Comment: the `.q` in the `rmdir` should be `/q`

Comment: Going forward you can read the help documentation for a command before asking a question about it. Open up a cmd prompt and type `set /?`. The syntax for the command does not show a space between the variable name and assignment operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N"

So - remove the errant spaces